# Show page from optional package in UWP

Tags: uwp

I want to add some features to my UWP app. Optional packages seem to be a way for that.
So I moved the ViewModel class and the Page class to the optional package and put them into the optional package's namespace.
After installing the optional package I want to show the moved Page, but I always get the following error:

```
Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException
  HResult=0x802B000A
  Message=XAML parsing failed.
  Source=System.Private.Interop
  StackTrace:
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.McgMarshal.ThrowOnExternalCallFailed(Int32 hr, RuntimeTypeHandle typeHnd) in f:\dd\ndp\fxcore\CoreRT\src\System.Private.Interop\src\Shared\McgMarshal.cs:line 1189
   at __Interop.ComCallHelpers.Call(__ComObject __this, RuntimeTypeHandle __typeHnd, Int32 __targetIndex, Void* arg0, Void* arg1, Int32 arg2)
   at Windows.UI.Xaml.IApplicationStatics__Impl.Stubs.LoadComponent(__ComObject __this, Object component, Uri resourceLocator, ComponentResourceLocation componentResourceLocation)
   at Windows.UI.Xaml.Application.__Factory_Windows_UI_Xaml__IApplicationStatics_LoadComponent(String typeName, Object component, Uri resourceLocator, ComponentResourceLocation componentResourceLocation)
   at Windows.UI.Xaml.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator, ComponentResourceLocation componentResourceLocation)
   at <my classes>
```

How can I load and show my optional package's Page?

Comment: Hello, From the error message, the problem may come from the XAML part of the Page you moved. Can you provide a minimum reproduced sample so that we can analyze this problem?

Comment: Hi @RichardZhang-MSFT, thanks for your answer. I will create a solution with minimal projects and put a link into a following comment.

Comment: @RichardZhang-MSFT I created a project at https://github.com/pinki/ShowPageOfOptionalPackageErrorSample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found out, that the generated `InitializeComponent()` method is wrong.

In my [sample code repository](https://github.com/pinki/ShowPageOfOptionalPackageErrorSample)'s `fixed` branch is a working solution.

In the code behind the optional package's Pages, the constructor's call of `InitializeComponent()` has to be replaced with the following code:

```cs
Uri resourceLocator = new Uri("ms-appx://ad4d8e16-9f9c-458f-ac0f-e74cb99fa10c/HalloPage.xaml");
Application.LoadComponent(this, resourceLocator, ComponentResourceLocation.Nested);
```

`ad4d8e16-9f9c-458f-ac0f-e74cb99fa10c` is the optional package's identity name. If you want to load images, resource dictionaries etc. you have to write the URIs in the same format including the optional package's identity name. Otherwise you will load resources from the main app.

It would be great, if the tool chain would generate the right URIs by itself.

Answer (score 0):

I checked your project, you added optional package project reference in the `MainApp` project, this is not the recommended development method for optional packages.

The optional package is additional, just like the DLC of the game, it will not affect the main app, nor is it a necessary reference for the main app project.

This means that the `MainApp` project and the optional package project need to be installed separately. In fact, you cannot reference another UWP application project in one UWP application project, their entry points are conflicting.

So please follow the steps below:

1. Remove the reference to the optional package project in the `MainApp` project.
2. Restore the `App.xaml` and `MainPage.xaml` files in the optional package project. (You can create a new UWP application project, which may be easier)
3. Modify the content of `Package.appxmanifest` in the optional package project, as mentioned in [this blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/archive/blogs/appinstaller/build-your-first-optional-package), remove the **Capability** tag, and add a reference to **MainPackageDependency**.

From these steps, you can find that the HalloPage class can no longer be directly referenced in the MainApp project. At the same time, even if the optional package is installed, you cannot get the page type through reflection.

So putting the page in an optional package may not be a suitable solution.

Comment: Thanks for checking my project. There never was an App.xaml inside the optional package's project. I followed these instructions (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/package/optional-packages-with-executable-code) that say that I had to reference the optional package's .winmd file to call the optional package's code. I'm a bit confused now.

Comment: If I build the page with C# code only, I can create an object of that page and set it as a Frame's content (using `NavigateTo` doesn't work), but I can't get it work with XAML pages.

Comment: Sorry, I missed something. In the [document](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/package/optional-packages-with-executable-code#c-optional-packages-with-executable-code-1), what you need to reference is the `winmd` file, which contains the type definition, that's the basis for you to access the types in the optional package in `MainApp`. In the **Bundle.mapping.txt** file, the winmd file needs to be referenced instead of the csproj file. However, in my test, ref the winmd file caused another loading error. I will report this problem and if there is new information I will post it here

Comment: I finally found a way to load xaml pages from optional packages. Is there a way to make the toolchain do the fixes for me?

Comment: Hello, I‘m glad that you have found a solution. You can mark your answer so that you can help more people who has the same problem. Regarding this workaround, this seems to be an internal resource management setting, you can ask this question in the Windows10 Feedback Hub application.