# Show image from Optional Package in UWP

Tags: uwp, package, option-type

I was try the solution in https://stackoverflow.com/a/63823702/4123782

But when I include the image in InitializeComponent by this code:

```cpp
Uri resourceLocator = new Uri("ms-appx://ad4d8e16-9f9c-458f-ac0f-e74cb99fa10c/HalloPage.xaml");
Application.LoadComponent(this, resourceLocator, ComponentResourceLocation.Nested);

Uri resourceLocatorImg = new Uri("ms-appx://ad4d8e16-9f9c-458f-ac0f-e74cb99fa10c/Assets/image.jpg");
Application.LoadComponent(this, resourceLocatorImg, ComponentResourceLocation.Nested);
```

When I show the optional package page. It crash and throw an error:

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: 'Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.'
> XamlParseException: The text associated with this error code could not be found.
> unrecognized input signature

My Code was in https://github.com/imlinhanchao/ShowPageOfOptionalPackageErrorSample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Derive from [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/package/optional-packages-with-executable-code#c-optional-packages-with-executable-code-1) about optional package, when you deploy main app project, you need to ensure that both packages are in sync. Please refer to the following steps to solve it.
In the main app project, navigate to the project build properties and select **Compile with .NET Native tool chain**. Go go to the project debug properties and select **Deploy optional packages**.

In addition, [Application.LoadComponent Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.application.loadcomponent?view=winrt-19041) is suitable for loading xaml files, not for loading pictures. So you could delete the code about loading image.

**Update:**

I suggest you could write image control in the HalloPage.xaml, which makes the image can be loaded along with the page. As follows:

HalloPage.xaml

```
<Page
   ……>
   <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock FontSize="72" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">Hallo Welt!</TextBlock>
            <Image Source="Assets/image.jpg" Height="600"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: I know how to use optional package. My question is how to  inlucde a image. I need to show a image in xaml page of optional package.

Comment: I have updated my answer, you could try it.

Comment: OK, I know what mistake I make.If I set a margin in image. For example, `<Image Source="Assets/image.jpg" Height="600" Margin="650,0,650,0"/> `. The image would be disappear. That is strange.

Comment: You set margin.left and margin.right to 650, which causes the total width of image horizontal margin and image width exceed window width, so the image was hidden. In addition, I recommend you use Stackpanel layout, you could read this [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/layout/layout-panels#stackpanel) to know much.